# Could not find default endpoint element that references contract

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, soap, wsdl

I have a ASP .NET MVC app that I want to be able to connect to SOAP API.

I have created a wrapper project were I have my common methods that are working with the API. I have created this wrapper because the file generated by tool is so huge the project build would take ages. 
From api doc site:

> The tool then generates a single file named EconomicWebService.cs with the proxy code. This file can then be included directly in a project (this can slow down your Visual Studio as it is a rather big file) or built into a dll that can be referenced from your project)

I have referenced this wrapper as dll in my class library (middle layer) that is referenced into my MVC application.

Sadly it is not working, and I am getting this error:

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'S2s.Economic.WebService.EconomicWebServiceSoap' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

**Webconfig**

```
<system.web>
   .....
</system.web>

<runtime>
...
</runtime>

<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
         <binding name="EconomicWebServiceSoap">
             <security mode="Transport" />
         </binding>
         <binding name="EconomicWebServiceSoap1" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://api.e-conomic.com/secure/api1/economicwebservice.asmx"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"  bindingConfiguration="EconomicWebServiceSoap"
            contract="PTS.S2s.Economic.WebService.EconomicWebServiceSoap"
            name="EconomicWebServiceSoap" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: endpoint must be in  "start project"  .config, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09138bex(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: What you mean by "start project" ?

Comment: Yep, I have it in webconfig for my startup project

Comment: I did not mean wsdl, but the cs file. Copied from the API info page.
To invoke the WSDL tool use https://api.e-conomic.com/secure/api1/economicwebservice.asmx?wsdl /protocol:SOAP12 (notice the SOAP12 - WSDL defaults to SOAP11). The WSDL tool is maintained by Microsoft and you can download the tool from their site.

The tool then generates a single file named EconomicWebService.cs with the proxy code. This file can then be included directly in a project (this can slow down your Visual Studio as it is a rather big file) or built into a dll that can be referenced from your project.

Comment: The config file references "PTS.S2s...", whereas the error message indicates it is looking for "S2s...". Try removing the "PTS" in the config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to find a workarround with manual endpoint setup in the code.

```
 EndpointAddress  endpoint = new EndpointAddress( "https://api.e-conomic.com/secure/api1/economicwebservice.asmx" );
```